# Tkinter file browser with send_key function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I wrote the following code to make a gui with a file chooser to upload a file to a website:

```
filename = StringVar()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("jpg",".jpg"),("png",".png"),("jpeg",".jpeg")))
y='"' +str(filename) + '"'
filepath = y.replace("/", str('\\'))
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"geckodriver.exe", options=options)
browser.get('url')
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input[2]').send_keys(filepath)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="b_upload"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="b_getsmiles"]'))).click()
smiles = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]').get_property('value')
print(smiles)
browser.close()
```

I choose the file over the file browser of tkinter and send it to the send_keys function
But after I choose the file over the tkinter file browser I get the follwing error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TMK\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1892, in call
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\TMK\Desktop\RoseBoom2.1alphaHolidayEdition Installation\RoseBoom2.1alphaHolidayEdition.py", line 12618, in cactus
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input[2]').send_keys(filepath)
File "C:\Users\TMK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
File "C:\Users\TMK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\TMK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\TMK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: "C:\Users\TMK\Desktop\anilin.png"
```

I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: It looks like you are adding quotes around the filename. That's probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ohhh noo... It's working now. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding quotes around the filename here:

```
y='"' +str(filename) + '"'
```

The filename should not have quotes around it.